# Select 2 focus on search on click/tab without unique ID

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using Select 2 4.0.13 on jQuery 3.6.1 and am looking for a way to allow the search bar to be selected when the Select 2 is opened.

I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/67691578/1278201 which does exactly what I need (and works when there are multiple select 2 on the page) however it "only" works when the select2 has an ID - if it just has a unique name/class then it does not work as the ID is
blank

```
$(document).on('select2:open', (e) => {
const selectId = e.target.id

$(".select2-search__field[aria-controls='select2-" + selectId + "-results']").each(function (
        key,
        value,
    ){
        value.focus();
    })
})
```

Looking at the markup, when the select2 has an ID of IDHERE it adds to each Select 2:

```
aria-owns="select2-IDHERE-results"
```

When there is no ID then this aria-owns is added using the name but with a "random" value included

```
aria-owns="select2-SELECTNAME-p5-results"
```

where P5 seems to random (i.e. another select 2 will use fu in place of p5 and so on.

Looking in the console, e returns both a target.name and a target.dataset.select2Id element but I cannot get any of those to work

Can another attribute be used to do this and target the relevant select 2 when the ID is not present and there are multiple select 2 on the same page?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to give it a (random) id. I had the problem too and for me this was the easiest way. (I´m using v4.1.0-rc)

```
function random() {
    return crypto.getRandomValues(new BigUint64Array(1))[0].toString(16);
}

$(".myselect:not(.select2-hidden-accessible)").attr('id', random()).select2()

$(document).on('select2:open', function(e) {
    document.querySelector(`[aria-controls="select2-${e.target.id}-results"]`).focus();
});
```

I dynamically create select2 fields, if you have several at once you can call it with a `each`.